# Win32 GUI accent not displayed even in UNICODE

Tags: c++, c, winapi, character-encoding

I'm making a GUI using window API with MSVC 2022,

When I try to display é char in my widget, there is a problem with encoding

[image: result]

That is the code for the widget:
I tried with wide string and the TEXT macro

```
CreateWindowW(
L"STATIC",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed
L"éééé",      // text
WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,  // Styles
10,         // x position
10,         // y position
250,        // Button width
50,        // Button height
hWnd,     // Parent window
NULL,       // No menu.
hInst,
NULL);      // Pointer not needed.

CreateWindowW(
L"BUTTON",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed
TEXT("réééé"),      // Button text
WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles
300,         // x position
10,         // y position
250,        // Button width
50,        // Button height
hWnd,     // Parent window
(HMENU)ID_OK,       // No menu.
hInst,
NULL);      // Pointer not needed.
```

My MSVC use UNICODE for the file (I checked in parameters) and defines UNICODE and _UNICODE.

Did I miss something ?

Thank you for your time

Thank to John is the comment, I solved the problem, the cpp file was saved in utf-8 instead of utf-16. This can be changed with the 'Save as' menu.

Comment: I would guess that MSVC has saved your source code as UTF-8. As a test try this `wchar_t title[5] = { 0xE9, 0xE9, 0xE9, 0xE9, 0 };` and then pass `title` as your window title (0xE9 being the Unicode value for é).

Comment: As an aside, all the `TEXT` or `_T` macro is doing is add the `L` prefix to the string. So no magic involved, but rather totally useless.

Comment: Put your source file somewhere so we can have a look

Comment: @john it worked ! You are right, it also worked with the text display. Is there a way to avoid construct array of wchar_t. It would be difficult to construct long sentences with

Comment: @Nathan When you save pick 'Save As...'. Then you get the file dialog but the Save Button is also a drop down menu. If you click on the down arrow you'll see a Save with encoding option. Pick the encoding you want (Windows 1252 works for me but YMMV). I think you only need to do this once, and future saves of that file will use the same encoding.

Comment: @Nathan But I must confess I don't really know what I'm talking about here, so you might need to experiment and do some research. But the general point is that when you are using string literals the encoding the files is saved in does matter.

Comment: @Nathan Another option is to use the `\u` escape. I.e. `L"\u00E9\u00E9"`. Then you aren't using any non-ASCII character in your string literals.

Answer (score 0):

> Did I miss something ?

Yes, the charset used in MVSC doesn't need to be the same than the one used in the library you are using, or the one selected at runtime.  Check your library documentation, to support UNICODE, as it seems to be showing your unicode sequences as iso-latin-1 character pairs.

IMHO Microsoft has taken long to adapt to unicode.  Despite MVSC already supports it, it is very probable that the Windows environment/library you use is not supporting it (or configured to) by default.  The comment you use in the `CreateWindowW` call is not enough to make it to assume UNICODE characters.  You'll probably need to specify it somewhere else.